# Combination of Teams Sets Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, combinations

We have N students with M students per team, and for sure N is divisible by M. so a recursive combination would do the trick.
For example 
N=6,N=2

> 12,34,56 is a combination
>
> 13,24,56 is another one

but the problem is that combinations generated can be repeated like

> 12,34,56
>
> 34,12,56

so is there any algorithm to generate non repeated sets of combinations ?

Also if i have an adjacency matrix like

> S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9
>
> 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
>
> 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0
>
> 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
>
> 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
>
> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
>
> 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
>
> 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
>
> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0

Where 1's represents which student used to work with other students, can i generate the combinations where the max number of students in a team worked with each other equals m/2 at max ?

Comment: is your example right ?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on how large N and M can be?

Comment: still, `N=6,N=2` what does that mean ?

Comment: N = number of students(1,2,3,4,5,6)     M=how many numbers are picked in each set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to tackle this problem, is assigning each student a team number. So if you have 6 students, and the teams must be of 2 students, then you have to build 3 teams. So `[0,0,1,1,2,2]` could be the representation of how students are teamed.

That is an array of size 6 (the number of students), and the value in each position represents the assigned team number. If I understood correctly, you don't want to distinguish that team from `[1,1,2,2,0,0]` as the same students are teamed together.

The way I would do that, is assigning each student a team number, from left to right. The first student will always be in team 0, and for any other student only assign a team number up to one more than the max team number already used in the students at the left of the array. So `[0,1,1,2,0,2]` would be a candidate representation of how students are teamed, but `[0,2,1,1,0,2]` not, because student in position 1 is assigned to team 2, but the team 1 isn't started yet.

The code to create such teams could be something like:

```
IEnumerable<int[]> CombineTeams(int numberOfStudents, int teamSize) {
    int numberOfTeams = numberOfStudents / teamSize;
    int[] studentsInTeam = new int[numberOfTeams]; // used to avoid assigning more than teamSize students into a same team
    studentsInTeam[0] = 1; // first student is initially assigned to team 0 from the start.
    List<int[]> teams = new List<int[]>(); // here all the possible teams will be stored
    int[] currentTeam = new int[numberOfStudents]; // used to assign the team numbers to studend
    AssignTeams(teamSize, currentTeam, teams, 1, 0, studentsInTeam); // start assigning team numbers from the second student, as the first will always be in team 0
    return teams;
}

void AssignTeams(int teamSize, int[] currentTeam, List<int[]> teams, int currentStudent, int maxTeam, int[] studentsInTeam) {
    if (currentStudent == currentTeam.Length) {
        int[] newTeam = new int[currentStudent];
        for (int s = 0; s < currentStudent; s++)
            newTeam[s] = currentTeam[s];
        teams.Add(newTeam);
    }
    else {
        for (int t = 0; t <= min(maxTeam+1, studentsInTeam.Length-1); t++) {
            if (studentsInTeam[t] < teamSize) {
                studentsInTeam[t]++;
                currentTeam[currentStudent] = t;
                AssignTeams(teamSize, currentTeam, teams, currentStudent+1, max(maxTeam, t), studentsInTeam);
                studentsInTeam[t]--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As this code creates all possible teaming combinations, there you'll find the one that maxes your teaming connections to M/2 if it exists (haven't give a thought to that last part). Hope this works for you.

Comment: What does the "s" variable in the else condition stands for ?

Comment: int[] currentTeam = new int[];  what is the size of that array ?

Comment: Sorry, fixed those mistakes.

Comment: When running your code with 9,3 it assigns 4 members to team 0 as start combination

Comment: Fixed the edge case. The first student is always assigned to team 0, and I missed setting the initial number of members of team 0 in 1.